# why does the code not work and return correct in the if statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement

```js
var question_list = ["What is 1 + 1", "What is 2 + 2"] 
var answer_list = [2, 4]
let currentNumber = 0;
let scoreboard = 0;

function submit() {
    let user_answer = $('#question-number').val()
    console.log(user_answer)
    console.log(answer_list[currentNumber])
    if (user_answer === answer_list[currentNumber]) {
        console.log("correct");
    } else {
        console.log("eror");
    }
}
submit();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="question-number" />
```

I am not sure why the if else statement gives me the else answer because
the terminal will print out
2
2
eror

Comment: Strings are not numbers

Comment: === fails as '2' is not 2 (mentionned by  epascarello). you have to do : let user_answer = parseInt($('#question-number').val())  ;

Comment: I made a snippet of your code as best I could.  Please edit to put the actual HTML in place and indicate how you trigger the `submit()` function to clarify your question details - note I did NOT put in place how you  execute the function since you did not indicate how - so it does not execute here without an edit by you - I just made a guess how.